# How to make storyboards for each device

Tags: ios, xcode

Actually, I made the view showed below. But every time I run the app on different devices they're moving their places. I added constraints by using Add Missing Constraints. You can see the problem I have. Can I solve it by drawing all storyboards for each device and how?

[Screenshots](http://postimg.org/gallery/2kc4obzzo/37e99c4d/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31738205/constraints-of-textfield-conflicting-with-uibutton/31738577#31738577

I answered this question here in the link

Comment: This is not good practice.  You should fully learn how to use Autolayout rather that just randomly adding missing constraints.  Your views should work for all device sizes.

Comment: You're not setting auto layout constraints properly... What would you like your app to match. Screenshot 1,2 or 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to get the view the way you want it using Storyboard. I'm assuming you know how to add constraints in Storyboard.

For the **yellow circle**, set height and width constraints Next add a center horizontally constraint. Finally pin it to the top.

For the **green and blue circles** set height and width constraints. Now set the height and width of the green circle equal to those of the blue circle. Pin the green circle's edge to left edge and the blue one to the left. Finally pin both to bottom.

Alternatively for the latter circles, you could choose to add both to a third view with the same constraints in said view and center the extra view horizontally while making sure to set its height and width constraints.

Comment: What is the logic while you're adding constraints?

Comment: I just learned it through trial and error so now it's just second nature. I have no method to provide you with, but if you keep at it it'll get easier eventually 